# MongoDB nested query returning null with Java driver

Tags: java, database, mongodb

I'm attempting to get the 'code' from the 'DEBIT' field from a mongodb collection formatted as follows:

```
  "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
 {...}
   "bookEntryActions" : {
    "CREATE" : [ 
        {
            "nature" : "DEBIT",
            "code" : "123"
        }, 
        {
            "nature" : "CREDIT",
            "code" : "456"
        }
    ],
    "DELETE" : [ 
        {
            "nature" : "DEBIT",
            "code" : "123"
        }, 
        {
            "nature" : "CREDIT",
            "code" : "789"
        }
    ]
 {...}
}
```

I've tried the following methods:

Method #1:

```
Document debitGlAccountCode = (Document)landlord.get("bookEntryActions.CREATE.1");
```

Method #2:

```
Document bookEntryActions = (Document) landlord.get("bookEntryActions");
Document creationRentCodes = (Document) bookEntryActions.get("CREATE");
ObjectId debitGlAccountCode = (ObjectId) creationRentCodes.get(Filters.eq("nature", "DEBIT"));
```

Method #3:

```
ObjectId debitGlAccountCode = (ObjectId) landlord.get(Filters.eq("bookEntryActions.CREATE.nature", "DEBIT"));
```

My issue is that of all the methods I've tried, the return for the .get("CREATE") is null. Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? I've verified that the CREATE field exists for all of the landlords using Robo3T.

Edit: each variable has gotten the data as follows

```
final MongoCollection<Document> landlordCollection = db.getCollection("landlord");
final FindIterable<Document> landlordDocs = landlordCollection.find();
MongoCursor<Document> llDocIter = landlordDocs.iterator();
while(llDocIter.hasNext()){
            Document landlord = llDocIter.next();
            LOGGER.info("landlord bookEntryActions: " + landlord.get("bookEntryActions"));
            LOGGER.info("landlord create: " + landlord.get("bookEntryActions.CREATE"));
            landlordArrayList.add(landlord);
        }
```

From there I have a foreach loop which goes through all the landlords in the arrayList and is where the previously attempted methods above are used. (Note: I'm using the array list for now as it's a little easier to work with while debugging. Eventually I will do everything in the while loop).

Comment: Can you add more java code to explain how each variable got data?

Comment: @Gibbs I updated the post with the appropriate info. Let me know if you need more clarification :)

Comment: How are you saying you are getting `null` and you need to cast to `List<Document>` instead `Document` when you get `bookEntryActions`

Comment: WRT getting null, when I run through the code with the debugger whenever I try to get "CREATION" the variable's value is null. 
As for casting to ```List<Document>``` I gave it a shot and it didn't work. It threw the following error: ```Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bson.Document cannot be cast to java.util.List```.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the way the database was set up "CREATE" is an array list of documents and thus I had just been working with the wrong data types. Upon adapting the code to work with the arraylist and not a Document its working.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the help! :)